# How to access SQL Server database using xamarin android mobile application

Tags: xamarin

Xamarin Android Mobile Application
SQL Server database is access at development phase but not generate after APK

Answer (score 0):

Generally, when you are unable to access a network resource on a "Release" build but you can on a debug build, it is due to a missing permission in the Android manifest. In this case, it could very well be the "Internet" permission, which grants network access to the app.

Please take a look at:

https://developer.xamarin.com/recipes/android/general/projects/add_permissions_to_android_manifest/

Comment: Thanks I have already try this thing but not working. I able to access Sql database in debug mode but not in release mode

Comment: The other option would be that the linker is linking something away that may be required. The way to test this is to disable the linker. In VS this is done via Properties > Android Options > Linker. In Xamarin Studio, Options > Android Build > Linker. Set the linker to "Don't Link" for Release builds such as https://db.tt/u2laJcRZ. Finally, please edit to include the connection code. You can remove the server name and password, just need to see how you are connecting. Thanks!